# Cannot set layout via constructor

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I tried almost everything but I just cant get the following to run.

```
<?php

class BaseController extends Controller {

  // Define frontpage layout manager
  protected $layout = '';

  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    $theme = Theme::where('enabled', '=', true)->first();

    // HERE !! : This never changes the value of $layout class var
    $this->layout = View::make('themes.front.' . $theme->folder . '.master'); 
    // I also tried without View::make(..)
    // I also checked that $theme returns something and it does return a theme


  }

  /**
   * Setup the layout used by the controller.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  protected function setupLayout()
  {
    if ( ! is_null($this->layout))
    {
      $this->layout = View::make($this->layout);
    }
  }

}
```

I simply cannot change the value of $layout in my constructor. I need this to allow user to switch between layouts.

Comment: Any errors? It should be without `View::make`. Only `$this->layout = 'themes.front.' . $theme->folder . '.master';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I wanted to achieve with this is: I would have multiple layouts (templates) and I would allow user to change these templates via administration so I needed a quick and easy way to manipulate the `protected $layout` value.

The problem with putting my code in `__constructor() {}` is that `setupLayout()` will override it and thus the error as no layout is found.

So there are two solutions:

**1) Declare layout in each sub-controller**
Meaning each controller that extends your base controller defines it's own `protected $layout` in it's own `__constructor() {}` method. However this is very repetitive if all your pages share the same template.

**2) Maniuplate the setupLayout() method**
Since all my pages share the same layout and I know for certian there  will always be at least one template I was able to simply alter the `setupLayout()` method to:

```
function setupLayout()
{
    $theme = Theme::where('enabled', '=', true)->first();
    $this->layout = 'themes.front.' . $theme->folder . '.master';
}
```